# Firefox extension: communicate with other application

Tags: javascript, sockets, firefox, plugins, tcp

What I want to do is: **automatically** run a browser (e.g. firefox), make it open a specific webpage, execute some javascript on the DOM and pass information to the **outside** (the outside might be the application that made firefox start).

What do you think would be the best way to achieve this? I thought of creating a firefox plugin that opens a tcp socket, listening to connections that trigger the execution of javascript code on the DOM. The result is then passed either to a local **webserver via http** or to the other end of the **socket connection**.

Would it also be possible to **start a webserver within the firefox plugin** instead? I think this would be easier than having a socket connection opened all the time (if not, this would be fine though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those who stumble across this question, I solved the problem by now.

The process is as follows:

1. A web server (in my case written in node.js) opens the browser via a shell command.
2. When the browser has initiated the plugin, it starts a socket server and sends an http request to the web server telling it to be ready to receive commands.
3. The web server sends the command "get-dom" with the web site as parameter to back to the browser (via socket).
4. The browser executes a content script on the website via a page-worker, creates a DOM object and sends it via http request back to the web server.